# My flutter application android build.gradle file does not have Default config and application ID

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.graddle file from my fresh flutter default app. How can i link the android aspect to firebase?

any resources with a recent date to this effect will be very much appreciated.

the problem i have with the code above is that their is no ApplicationID. I am thinking something is wrong with my build.graddle, which makes me question my installation of flutter or android studio or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your build.gradle. You're just looking into Root level of build.gradle file of android in your flutter project. You need to check into android/app/build.gradle.

There are two build.gradle file in an android project.

1. android/build.gradle
2. android/app/build.gradle (check here)

See the screenshot of my selected file and it's path.

[image]